# Cortana-Activate app using text

Tags: winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, cortana

I need help in understanding how I can search or activate my app using Cortana.
I have integrated the VCD file and able to launch my application using Speech.
I also wanted to activate my app when User searches with keyword on windows instead of using Speech.
Any pointers!!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Remember, Cortana requires the moniker you selected for your app. When you have to say "`MyApp` do my command", you must also type "`MyApp` do my command".

So here are the two things to remember:

1. Cortana works fine without a microphone
2. Typing to Cortana has the same rules
3. When your app is activated, you can ask how it was activated (voice | type)

Best of luck!

Comment: hi Jerry, my App responds to Voice Commands and fails when i use text queries.I have tried several times .I used the same command that i used for Voice and it does not take me to my app. As a work around, i am trying to use Setting Content file.But i am struck at understanding what are LowKeyWords,highkeyWords ?Anyone can give me pointers around understandign the setting content and configure it to my app.